# Set initial Zoom for base64 data uri pdf

Tags: html, asp.net, base64

I am able to display a pdf in my aspx page. How ever I want to set it's initial zoom level (I'm using google chrome)

```
string base64PDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
base64PDF = base64PDF + "#page=1&zoom=50";
string str = "<embed src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + base64PDF 
            + "' type='application/pdf' width='1800px' height='800px' />";
pdfdiv.InnerHtml = str;
```

code works, and displays the pdf but didn't really set the initial zoom level. Whatever value I place within `"zoom  = 100"`, nothing really changes. Also tried `#zoom=50` although I think this would only work on .pdf

Comment: Note: this comment is for another question.Sorry about that, from my understanding, the outcome could be different on other computer if I use the default, and therefore should specify it? upon checking I got "iso-8859-1"

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. The docs imply that the outcome could be different on even the same computer (it presumably depends on user region settings).